# Local notifications and storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, storyboard

I'm wondering what would be the best way to accomplish my goal. I have an iPhone app that is using storyboards and has a tabbar controller as the root view. Under one of the tabs I need to show a view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller and is about 3 slides deep when a local notification is pressed.

Any ideas of the best way to do this? Going to continue with trying to implement this in a clean way and I will post if no one has a response, but some help in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the method I was after:

- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated

And since I wanted to use existing viewcontrollers that had layouts for my view from the storyboard I pulled them in using this and initialized what I need. Help this helps someone else in the future.

- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier

Comment: did this method work for you when you app isn't running at all, ie not even in the background?

Comment: Yes it worked for me, but the method won;t run while it is in the background. When the app appears in the foreground that is when the method will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `userInfo` property on the `UILocalNotification` class. Setup a string with the name of the controller you want to show.

Catch the notifications with:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

In the AppDelegate. Then search for the string you save on the UILocalNotification and use the next method in the `UINavigationController:`

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

In order to show the appropiate viewcontroller. If you want your app to show always the same view controller you don't need to setup the `userInfo`, you only need to implement the `UINavigationController` method above.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It seems to me that this method would not allow navigation back to previous views in the navigation stack. The view I am after is 3rd in a stack of navigation controllers. If 1 and 2 doesn't have the data needed to initialize I would be out of like with this approach.